# declaring unrelated class but it does not run correctly

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that needs stacks. I declare stack and then an unrelated class. But I cannot find out why the program does not work?

This is my stack:

```
    template <class T>
class stack :public base<T>
{
private:
    T *stackarray;
    int top;
    int stacksize;
    int arraysize;

public:
    stack(int);
    void push(T);

template <class T>
stack<T>::stack(int x)
{
    arraysize = x;
    stackarray = new T[arraysize];
    top = -1;
    stacksize = 0;

}

template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T a)
{
    if (top < arraysize - 1)
    {
        top++;
        *(stackarray + top) = a;
        stacksize++;
    }

    else
        return 0;
}
```

and this is my unrelated class:

```
class unrelated {
private:
    string str;

public:
    void set(string);
    string get();
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& output, unrelated &b)
    {
        output << b.get();
        return output;
    }
};

void unrelated::set(string y)
{
    str = y;
}

string unrelated::get()
{
    return str;
}
```

And now I add these two lines to my main function:

```
stack<unrelated> unrelated_stk(20);
unrelated_stk.push('h');
```

I derived "unrelated_stk" and I think the second line should run without problem since there is push method that already declared in stack. But it does not work and it reads this error in c::B

> error: no matching function for call to 'stack::push(char)'|

Should I re-declare "push" method in "unrelated" class. But this does not make sense. what is my problem?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `stack<T>::push()` shouldn't return 0 on fail, since its return type is `void`; it should probably throw an exception of some sort instead.  Alternatively, if the return type wasn't supposed to be `void`, the `if` block doesn't return anything.  If you run into any other unexpected behaviour regarding `push()`, that may be worth looking into as a possible cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `T` becomes `unrelated` not `char`, so the `push` method will take an `unrelated` object as its argument, not a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `unrelated_stk.push('h');` you're pushing a `char` not an `unrelated`. And note that it's a `char`, not a literal string, since you used single quotes. Since `unrelated` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `char` (it doesn't have a constructor at all!), the compiler doesn't know how to make an `unrelated` from the `char` and so it doesn't know what to do.